# How to execute select Query with in Single Quote in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
set Q1= 'SELECT ID, EnquiryID, EnquiryDate, CompanyName, ContactPerson FROM EnquiryHeader WHERE ';
set Q1 = concat(Q1,RefID);
```

in the above Query RefID is paramete vale in Procedure
and RefID values is 'DelFlg=0 and EnquirySource=3'

so how to execute Q1 in MYSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
set @Q1 = CONCAT('SELECT ID, EnquiryID, EnquiryDate, CompanyName, ContactPerson FROM Syscon.EnquiryHeader WHERE ',RefID);

PREPARE makeQ FROM @Q1;
EXECUTE makeQ;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE makeQ;
```